# How to retrieve all the table details between min(date1) and maximum(date)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE From_date between '2013-01-03'
AND '2013-01-09'
```

how to take min(date1) and max(date2) to be used on the above query

Comment: Please show some input data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to store min and max dates of your table

```
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATE
DECLARE @MaxDate AS DATE

SELECT @MinDate=MIN(From_date) , @MaxDate=MAX(From_date)
FROM table
```

Then use them in your query

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE From_date between @MinDate AND @MaxDate
```